# Simple low-power remote switch

Tags: mosfet, switches, polarity

I volunteer with a charity making aids for people with a disability.  My current project is a key-fob gate latch for a client who can't reach a latch from the wheelchair. I have only a bit of hobby experience with electronics, so searching the web I came up with this attached design.[image: attached design]

I have selected the Fairchild MOSFET becuase it seems to be in the appropriate voltage range and is easily available in small quantities.  I have not been able to work out how to size the resistors that will drop the gate voltage from the signal 12V, so I guessed.

Can anyone advise me whether the MOSFET component is appropriate and tell me how to calculate the size of the resistor please?

Comment: I'm not sure this circuit does what you want, and if you press both buttons you may well kill both MOSFETs. Describe what you want to do in a bit more detail.

Comment: what's a `key-fob gate latch`? ... please add information about manufacturer, model number, datasheet (anything may help) ... add a picture if you can

Comment: It says 10k or thereabouts will be fine , This FET or equivalent is OK. Keep wire pairs short and twisted.

Comment: _"searching the web I came up with this attached design"_ - where did this design come from?

Comment: I realise that pressing both buttons would result in misery.  The key-fob device is detailed here <https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/173600072309> and is a two-channel RF switch.  I want the user to be able to press button A to unlock the gate and button B to lock it again.  I've got the solenoid attached to an arm that throws a bolt out into a keeper in the gate.

Comment: The basic design came up in pretty much every tutorial on MOSFETs as switches on the web.  These were all explaining the principles.  Most commonly they used a microprocessor to activate a 5V line on the gate.